# How to test a tflite model with an image in the cmd line?

Tags: python, tensorflow, cmd

I recently converted my 'output_graph.pb' to 'Skystone.tflite', but when I put it into my application it showed no objects detected.  How can I test that I trained the model properly?  Is there a way use the cmd line to give it an image and get a confidence level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so after a long time of research I found a script called Label_Image, from the Tensorflow for poets 2.  This script's inputs were 'graph' and 'image', which worked out perfectly.

[tensorflow for poets 2](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2)

Comment: The codelab does not exist anymore , can you share the code ?